# simple query Delete records in a table based on count logic

Tags: sql, plsql

a table with a pk and status column which is having values as 'Y','N','NULL'

Query:

get the count of records with status column as 'Y', if this count exceeds 1% of total count of records then dont delete , else delete the records in the table.

i tried like this

```
Declare   
  v_count Number;   
  v_count1 Number;   
BEGIN   
  v_count := select count(*) from temp; 
  v_count1 := select count(*) from temp where status = 'Y' ;

  v_count := v_count + ((0.1) * (v_count))

  if (v_count1 > v_count)
  {
    insert into  temp1 values(pk,status)
  } 
  else
  {   
    Delete from temp ;
  }
END;
```

Comment: can u explain more .what u want u want to delete or insert .....

Comment: delete the records from temporary table where status is 'Y'when the if condition doesn't satisfy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Declare   
v_count Number;   
v_count1 Number;   
BEGIN   
select count(*) into v_count from temp; 
select count(*) into v_count1 from temp where status = 'Y' ;

v_count := v_count + ((0.01) * (v_count))

if (v_count1 > v_count)
{
  insert into  temp1 values(pk,status)
} 
else
{   
  Delete from temp ;
}
END;
```

correct your function sql queries like this .......enjoy

Comment: but only 1% of count of records means 0.01 ?

Comment: if this is for bulk records.. can i use the same or need to include the whole code in a cursor